# How to make a program run at startup?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, startup

I want my c++ program to run automatically when the operating system loaded , i mean when the system starts working ..
I am using linux(ubutu)
I have no idea to do that ?
any idea may help .. thanks in advance

Comment: This question is off-topic here.  It's not a programming question, it's a system administration question.  Given you're on Ubuntu, http://askubuntu.com/ might be a good fit.

Answer (score 4):

(*The fact that your program is written in C++ is irrelevant to this answer.*)

Simply add a symbolic link to your executable in `/etc/init.d/`.

E.g. if your program is in `/home/username/soft/myprog`, run:

```
ln -s /home/username/soft/myprog /etc/init.d/
```

Make sure the file is executable.

Comment: thanks .. but i am wonder if i can undo this or not ?

Comment: Of course, you can always delete the link: `rm /etc/init.d/myprog`.

Comment: Haha! I'll make an exception to the SO "no social networking" rules on this one and say hello! Very useful, thanks! ^^

Answer (score 2):

**An alternate way that might be helpful**

Open your `.bashrc` file (That can be found in the home directory i.e `~/.bashrc`)
Add to it the line :

`./program_executable_path`

Also note that the program must have *execute* permission.
You can grant the permission by using `chmod`:
`$chmod u+x program_executable_path`

Comment: This runs the program when you start a shell, not the OS.

Comment: Surely the editor is irrelevant here?

Comment: Yes it was . Done the corrections. Please correct me if i am wrong, but bashrc is also executed when you log in.

Comment: i have to add it to the .profile file